# How to override the @media css property into the experince cloud site?

Tags: community, css, community-builder, experience-cloud, style

I am using the **citizen theme** in the experience cloud site. I am trying to change the **menu text color** but am not able to do that using the configuration.

So I am trying to add custom CSS to override the color of the menu item.
I have tried the below CSS but no luck.

Can anyone please correct me? where i am doing wrong?

```
.forceCommunityThemeNav .mainNavItem .linkBtn {
    color: #ff0000 !important;    
}

.forceCommunityThemeNav .mainNavItem a {
     color: #ff0000 !important;   
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
        .forceCommunityThemeNav .mainNavItem .linkBtn {
            color: #ff0000 !important; 
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, how to change the navigation text colour using the configuration. I have followed the steps provided in [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_theme-g-header.htm&type=5) documentation.

- Click on the Compact Header
- In the Compact Header configuration click on the link section.
- You can find it here below options:

  - Link Color
  - Link Hover Color
  - Link Active Border Color
  - Link Text Shadow Color

[image]